# Wrapping Sidekiq's perform method to add timezone awareness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a rails application with a dynamically configured time zone.  It is stored in a database table containing other options, and the rails application itself is configured to UTC (default).

I've made the application itself aware of the timezone with a simple `around` filter using `Time.use_zone(..., &block)`.

I would like to do something similar for my Sidekiq workers.  Some of them process data that has timezone relevance, so they need it.  I don't see any filtering options available in Sidekiq itself, no callbacks, before/after type things I can hook into.  My current solution is to a `prepend` a module, like so:

```
module TimeZoneAwareWorker

  def perform(*args)
    Time.use_zone(Options.time_zone) do
      super
    end
  end

end
```

and mixed in:

```
class MyWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker

  prepend TimeZoneAwareWorker

  ...

end
```

This works fine for simple workers, but breaks down if the `prepend` occurs in the same class as the `include Sidekiq::Worker`.  If the worker is subclassed, the hierarchy doesn't work out for the prepended `perform` to wrap the implementation.

Is there a better way?  *Ultimately it seems what I really want is a foolproof method of wrapping a single method with another method, and yielding the wrapped implementation.*

I know my other option is monkeypatching before/after/around type callbacks into Sidekiq's implementation, but I'd like to only go there if forced.

Comment: look at this: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware

Comment: Oh that's fantastic!  Please put this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sidekiq has its own [middleware](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware) solution:

> Sidekiq has a similar notion of middleware to Rack: these are small
>   bits of code that can implement functionality. Sidekiq breaks
>   middleware into client-side and server-side.
>
> - Client-side middleware runs before the pushing of the job to Redis and allows you to modify/stop the job before it gets pushed. Client
>     middleware may receive the class argument as a Class object or a
>     String containing the name of the class.
> - Server-side middleware runs 'around' job processing. Sidekiq's retry feature is implemented as a simple middleware.

You can easily create your own middleware agent to add the timezone awareness code.